# JSON flattener returning only last object from JSON to a flattened form

Tags: java, arrays, json, collections

I have a JSON that looks like below,

```
 {
  "users": [
    {
      "displayName": "Sharad Dutta",
      "givenName": "",
      "surname": "",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuerAssignedId": "kkr007@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "VET",
      "extension_locale": "en-GB",
      "extension_tenant": "EG12345"
    },   
    {
      "displayName": "Sharad Dutta",
      "givenName": "",
      "surname": "",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuerAssignedId": "kkr007@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "VET",
      "extension_locale": "en-GB",
      "extension_tenant": "EG12345"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the above code and it is able to flatten the JSON like this,

```
{
  "extension_timezone": "VET",
  "extension_tenant": "EG12345",
  "extension_locale": "en-GB",
  "signInType": "userName",
  "displayName": "Wayne Rooney",
  "surname": "Rooney",
  "givenName": "Wayne",
  "issuerAssignedId": "pdhongade007",
  "extension_user_type": "user"
}
```

But the code is returning only the last user in the "users" array of JSON. It is not returning the first user (essentially the last user only, no matter how many users are there) just the last one is coming out in flattened form from the "users" array.

```
public class TestConvertor {
    
    static String userJsonAsString;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        
        String userJsonFile = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\jsonRes\\json_format_user_data_input_file.json";
                
                try {
                    userJsonAsString = readFileAsAString(userJsonFile);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
        
        
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(userJsonAsString); // this is your input
        Map<String, Object> flatKeyValue = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        System.out.println("flatKeyValue : " + flatKeyValue);
        readValues(object, flatKeyValue);
        System.out.println(new JSONObject(flatKeyValue)); // this is flat
    }

    static void readValues(JSONObject object, Map<String, Object> json) throws JSONException {
        for (Iterator it = object.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            String key = (String) it.next();
            Object next = object.get(key);
            readValue(json, key, next);
        }
    }

    static void readValue(Map<String, Object> json, String key, Object next) throws JSONException {
        if (next instanceof JSONArray) {
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) next;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {
                readValue(json, key, array.opt(i));
                
            }
        } else if (next instanceof JSONObject) {
            readValues((JSONObject) next, json);
        } else {
            json.put(key, next);
        }
    }
    private static String readFileAsAString(String inputJsonFile) throws Exception {
            
            return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(inputJsonFile)));
    }
}
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong or my code needs modification.

Comment: The JSON you have is incorrect.
Use this to check it and update your question with a valid JSON
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Comment: How is that JSON incorrect? Can you explain me? Because it is a multidimensional JSON wrapped inside an array "users".

Comment: have you checked with the link I added in the comment?. 
It states that the JSON is missing a closing bracket for the object and a closing bracket for the array.
Other than that, why are you storing the users in such a way? 
you can make an array called users and store multiple objects of users in it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realised I missed the JSON, yes you are correct, JSON is wrong, I will update in answer.

Comment: I have fixed the JSON, mistake from my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below approach, this will give you a comma separated format for both user and identifier (flat file per se),

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, ParseException {
    
            String userJsonFile = "path to your JSON";
            final StringBuilder sBuild = new StringBuilder();
            final StringBuilder sBuild2 = new StringBuilder();
            
            try {
                String userJsonAsString = convert your JSON to string and store in var;
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject output = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(userJsonAsString);
            try {
                
                JSONArray docs = (JSONArray) output.get("users");
                Iterator<Object> iterator = docs.iterator();
                
                
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    JSONObject userEleObj = (JSONObject)iterator.next();
                    JSONArray nestedIdArray = (JSONArray) userEleObj.get("identities");
                    Iterator<Object> nestIter = nestedIdArray.iterator();
                     
                    while (nestIter.hasNext()) {
                        JSONObject identityEleObj = (JSONObject)nestIter.next(); 
                        identityEleObj.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> sBuild2.append(identityEleObj.get(key) + ","));
                        userEleObj.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
                            if (StringUtils.equals((CharSequence) key, "identities")) {
                                sBuild.append(sBuild2.toString());
                                sBuild2.replace(0, sBuild2.length(), "");
                            } else {
                                sBuild.append(userEleObj.get(key) + ","); 
                            }
                                
                        });
                         
                    }
                    sBuild.replace(sBuild.lastIndexOf(","), sBuild.length(), "\n");  
                }
                
                System.out.println(sBuild);
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```